# Read incoming pin-pad number from RS232 using Web-Relay

Tags: php, web-services, networking, hardware

This is something unusual I am doing other than coding. So My question is bit tricky and for those who have some knowledge of hardware programming I think so.

So all I am doing is, I bought one web Relay device from Hw group and it's called IP Relay ER02b. Which has two inputs 1 & 2 and that I am controlling through command prompt like on/off using web relay device IP address.

However, I have one more pin-pad device which is connected to web Relay into port called RS232. So there is no direct connection to my laptop with pin-pad device.

So the question is, how I can read incoming pin-pad numbers using IP address of web relay using command prompt as I searched a lot and couldn't find the way to do this using command prompt or PHP as PHP is also fine.

Any help on this will be appreciate and if need any further information then please let me know and I'll more than happy to provide.

Thank you guys in advanced

Comment: I really have no idea about these devices, but [the manual](http://www.hw-group.com/products/ip_relay/IP-Ethernet-Relay-ER02b_en.html) says "*Ethernet IO can be controlled over the Web, Modbus/TCP or Telnet NVT*". You could try looking at the source code when connecting by the web (ports 80 or 443), or maybe when connecting via Modbus/TCP (port 502) or Telnet (port 23) it might give you some sort of a welcome message with this information. If not, maybe there is some sort of command you can execute on the device using Telnet to get the info you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply Mike but I am already controlling using port 23 and IP address to relay input's but no idea regarding how to read RS232 connection of web relay to read input from the Pin-pad which is connected to RS232 port on webRelay.....